# Angular - Issue with Routing Views Coming From .NET MVC 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am having issues setting up my Angular project with .NET MVC 5.0. I am not sure what's wrong with the below code. When I run the application, unexpectedly to me, app shows the template set in app-component.ts and not login

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },


    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
];
```

To test out the things, and ignore MVC controller/view routing for a second, I also tried creating html file inside in my login folder,

```
 @Component({

    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login-component.html' -- This was initially /Public/Login -Path to the MVC controller
})
```

Project is shared on a github project here

https://github.com/GAK-MPRO/AngularMVCStarter/tree/Master/A2Rnd

My question is.. what do I need to do to route my views using MVC routing with views rendered by calling controllers.

Comment: Is the login html being displayed on the page?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose : No

Comment: Do you have a router outlet defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order in which your routes are defined. The default routes should always be at the end of the route list:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch:'full' },


    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch:'full' }
];
```

I just looked at your code on git hub. The bootstrap module is trying to bootstrap appcomponent and the appcomponent does not have an router-outlet tag. Edit the template in the app.component.ts file to include

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and it should show you both app component and login components html content.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><br/><router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: I have a big doubt this will work, what has order to do with paths , it is an array, and I believe internally it would searching the route that matches

Comment: I just looked at your code on git hub. The bootstrap module is trying to bootstrap appcomponent  and the appcomponent does not have an router-outlet tag. Edit the template in the app.component.ts file to include <router-outlet></router-outlet> and it should show you both app component and login components html content

Comment: @ Praveen : That worked. Thanks. Last piece that I am struggling with is how to use MVC routing . I have my views rendered by the MVC controllers. So I have server side routing which would deliver my views, but those routes are different from Angular routes. For e.g.. I have /Public/Authenticate controller that return a view from server, but on the angular side it /Login. With your solution, I got the part working, but when I refreshed the screen, I got a server error that route cannot be found. I then added, a fallback route , it took care of that situation. however...

Comment: ... I have to add,routes for the views that would come from MVC server side